# AWS MediaConvert: Any way to detect input codec and other metadata?

Tags: amazon-web-services, metadata, video-processing, aws-media-convert

I'm using AWS MediaConvert, and I can't find a way to get metadata from the input video. Specifically, I need length, dimensions, and codec. I'm really surprised I can't do it.

I can grab the length and dimensions from the output, but I can't find a way to get the input codec.

It would be super helpful if I could do this through MediaConvert since it is already reading the video file. Otherwise, I have to come up with some other process to read the video file and grab the codec metadata. I think I'd have to set up an entirely new server just to do it, due to volume.

For more detail my process looks something like this:

1. A user uploads a video (it goes directly to s3)
2. A lambda function is triggered, which kicks off the MediaConvert job
3. MediaConvert does its thing
4. Another lambda function is triggered when the job is complete and writes metadata to my db

Any thoughts on how I could possibly grab the codec without creating yet another process that reads the whole file would be much appreciated!

Comment: Unfortunately I have not found a solution and ended up building a lambda function that runs ffprobe to pull the metadata. Luckily, it you feed ffprobe a URL, it looks like it doesn't have to pull the whole file down just to get the metadata. Still, would LOVE to be able to pull this from aws mediaconvert. Seems like an obvious feature.

Comment: Hi, It seems you used ffprobe to find the format. Did you get any better solution for this?